# passport-jwt, not throing error, but not authenticating. wont even console.log

Tags: express, jwt, passport.js

I am trying to authenticate using passport-jwt, express etc.
I currently am not getting authenticated, but most troubling is that I cant seem to console.log inside the function... nothing happens.

Here is the full passport.js

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport) {
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromHeader();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;

    console.log(opts); // THIS SHOW PRIORE TO THE EXPRESS LISTEN MSG!

    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {

        console.log(jwt_payload); // THIS DOESNT EVER SHOW!

        User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
                // or create a new account
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

the users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

const config = require('../config/database');
const User = require('../models/user');

...code removed for brevity...

router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req,res,next) => {
    res.json({user: req.user});
});


module.exports = router;
```

Any ideas on how I can 'see' my payload so I can find whats going on?

Im using postman to hit 'http://localhost:3000/users/profile' 
passing headers "authentication" and the token "JWT my-token..."

THx - I realize this is a bit of an odd request...The tutorial I was following, indicates I should be able to see the payload, even if i am not authenticated...
So Im kinda stuck with no idea where to turn.

Answer (score 0):

UGH - this is the second time I've continued to plug away at something after I asked, only to hit upon a solution. apperantly the version Im am using is newer than the examples and ExtractJwt.fromHeader() should be .fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt"). It is frustrating that it did not error, and did not progress enough to log, however - NOW I get my console log, and can see my payload... I hope this helps someone else. (I am frustrated with the pace and changes made to js libs, that destroy backwards compatibility, and do not clearly document a path, I understand kinda why it happens, but it makes learning and troubleshooting very frustrating)